# Java Maths (Runtime Memory Percentage)

Tags: java, math, runtime, percentage

I'm sure I've made some sort of extremely stupid mistake here.
I've got this code:

```
private static String generateRAM()
{
    final long RAM_TOTAL = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
    final long RAM_FREE = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
    final long RAM_USED = RAM_TOTAL - RAM_FREE;
    final long RAM_TOTAL_MB = RAM_TOTAL / 8 / 1024;
    final long RAM_FREE_MB = RAM_FREE / 8 / 1024;
    final long RAM_USED_MB = RAM_USED / 8 / 1024;
    final double RAM_USED_PERCENTAGE = (RAM_USED / RAM_TOTAL) * 100;
    return RAM_TOTAL_MB + "MB TOTAL / " + RAM_FREE_MB + "MB FREE / " + RAM_USED_MB + "MB USED (" + RAM_USED_PERCENTAGE + "%)"; 
}
```

This returns:

```
15440MB TOTAL / 11809MB FREE / 3630MB USED (0.0%)
```

The percentage is obviously incorrect. 
How does this happen?
I am, to the best of my knowledge, doing all my maths right.
If I punch the given numbers into a calculator and find the percentage myself I get 23.5, my expected result.

I'm sure I've just made a horrible mistake that I'll kick myself for, could anybody enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
final double RAM_USED_PERCENTAGE = (RAM_USED / RAM_TOTAL) * 100;
```

To

```
final double RAM_USED_PERCENTAGE = ((RAM_USED * 1.0) / RAM_TOTAL) * 100;
```

This is because Java is interpreting the result as a `long` / `long` division, so the result will be a `long` value i.e. 5 / 10 => 0. By applying a factor of 1.0 of any of the operands, the compiler will do a `double` / `long` operation, that will result in a `double` value.

Comment: Thanks! Really helpful. I'll accept this answer as soon as SO lets me. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
final double RAM_USED_PERCENTAGE = (RAM_USED / RAM_TOTAL) * 100;
```

It is because integer divison. Cast one of the types to double.

Example:

```
final double RAM_USED_PERCENTAGE = ((double)RAM_USED / RAM_TOTAL) * 100;
```

As per [JLS 15.17.2. Division Operator /](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2)

> Integer division rounds toward 0. That is, the quotient produced for operands n and d that are integers after binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is an integer value q whose magnitude is as large as possible while satisfying |d · q| ≤ |n|. Moreover, q is positive when |n| ≥ |d| and n and d have the same sign, but q is negative when |n| ≥ |d| and n and d have opposite signs.
>
> There is one special case that does not satisfy this rule: if the
>   dividend is the negative integer of largest possible magnitude for its
>   type, and the divisor is -1, then integer overflow occurs and the
>   result is equal to the dividend. Despite the overflow, no exception is
>   thrown in this case. On the other hand, if the value of the divisor in
>   an integer division is 0, then an ArithmeticException is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 errors. `freeMemory()` and `totalMemory()` returns a number of bytes, so to convert it into MB you have to divide it twice by 1024 (kB and MB), then by 8. Plus, you have to convert RAM_USED to a double, in order to compute this as a floating point operation:

```
private static String generateRAM()
{
    final long RAM_TOTAL = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
    final long RAM_FREE = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
    final long RAM_USED = RAM_TOTAL - RAM_FREE;
    final long RAM_TOTAL_MB = RAM_TOTAL / 1024 / 1024;
    final long RAM_FREE_MB = RAM_FREE  / 1024 / 1024;
    final long RAM_USED_MB = (double) RAM_USED / 1024 / 1024;
    final double RAM_USED_PERCENTAGE = ((double) RAM_USED / RAM_TOTAL) * 100;
    return RAM_TOTAL_MB + "MB TOTAL / " + RAM_FREE_MB + "MB FREE / " + RAM_USED_MB + "MB USED (" + RAM_USED_PERCENTAGE + "%)";
}
```

which returns:

```
10MB TOTAL / 9MB FREE / 0MB USED (2.47130735892926%)
```

Comment: Didn't notice that, I originally displayed it in KB.
I changed the variable names and the text, but not the actual Maths.
Thanks.

Comment: +1 because that's true. I don't think OP's using a 16GB RAM machine: *15440MB TOTAL*

Comment: Suprisingly no,  I'm not. :P

Comment: Why would you divide by 8? Bytes are not bits.

Comment: @FrankPavageau you're right, I mixed up bytes and bits :) I updated the code accordingly.